# How can I cancel the selecting Event for a TabControl

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

I am handling tab change in the WinForms TabControl's Deselecting event. However, in some cases I am deleting the tab that I clicked on before I switch to it.

scenario

I have tab 1 and tab 2
currently I'm in tab 1
I click on tab 2
tab 1 Deselecting Event Removes Tab 2 from the tab collection
Crashes at OnPaint because it's trying to go to a tab that no longer exists. (ArgumentOutOfRangeException). It crashes before it hits the Selecting Event.

I don't want to see if the tabcount changed in deselecting because I only want to cancel if the tab I'm going to no longer exists.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void TabControl_Deselecting( object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs ) {
       DoSomeWork();
    }
```

Assume that DoSomeWork deletes the Tab I clicked on. How can I find out if it did delete the tab I was intending to go to?

Comment: Could you clarify the question a little more and what the desired outcome is @fahed.  Having trouble understanding what you want here.

Comment: You need to rethink your user interface.  It sounds way too confusing and difficult to use.

Comment: the Tab removal is 3 or 4 functions deep, whoa thats a bit over the top. Are you `binding` controls to business objects and putting ALL the logic in the business object? The way this GUI functions sounds really un-intuitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No repro.  The scenario is strange but I can't get it to crash.  Do make sure you cancel the Deselect.

```
    private void tabControl1_Deselecting(object sender, TabControlCancelEventArgs e) {
        if (e.TabPageIndex == 0 && tabControl1.TabCount > 1) {
            tabControl1.TabPages[1].Dispose();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: let me see how i can get e.cancel set to true in deselect. that would solve the issue.

Comment: the problem is that the tab removal is 3 or 4 functions deep in the code

Comment: Whatever you are doing, it is completely invisible from here, you are doing it wrong.  You'll need to document your question better, a snippet that reproduces the problem is required.

Answer (score 0):

One of possible solution that comes in my mind:

if you are sure that `Tab1` Deselect event raised before `Tab2` Select event, I would *try*, to declare my custom tab control and override it's `OnPaintMethod`, like this **pseudocode**:

```
public class MyCustomTab : TabItem
{
   ...


   protected override OnPaint(....)
   {
      if(this.Parent == null) return;

       base.Paint(...);
   }    
}
```

Clear that to your `TabControl` you should add TabItems of that type.